# How I Creat TIMESTAMP field while migration in CODEIGNITER with CURRENT_TIME on update

Tags: codeigniter, database-migration

Below is my code please tell me where i m wrong..

```
public function up(){

        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
                'id'=> array(
                    'type'          => 'int',
                    'constraint'    => 11,
                    'auto_increment'=> TRUE,
                ),
                'ip_address'=> array(
                    'type'      => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint'=> '40',
                ),
                'login'=> array(
                    'type'      => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint'=> '50',
                ),
                'time'=> array(
                    'type'      => 'timestamp',
                    'Default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
                    'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' => TRUE,
                ),
        ));
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('login_attempts');
    echo "table created";       
    }
```

and this error will generate on running migration

> Error Number:
>
> 1067
>
> Invalid default value for 'time'
>
> CREATE TABLE login_attempts ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   ip_address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, time
>   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', CONSTRAINT
>   pk_login_attempts PRIMARY KEY(id) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
>   COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
>
> Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/tank_auth/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Answer (score 5):

Look at the default value of the `time` column. In MySQL `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` mustn't be in single brackets. As CodeIgniter does automatically escape default value for security reasons, you can alternatively pass an entire string like:

```
'time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
```

Leave other columns as arrays as they already are. Change the time column only as shown above.